# Improve transmit rate of winpcap

Tags: c++, network-programming, bandwidth, ethernet, winpcap

I'm trying to stress test some new hardware by transmitting a lot of data through the ethernet layer to see how i handles it. For this I'm using my laptop, windows 7 x64 and winpcap.

I create a send queue in a thread and then transmit that. I have made a scheme where one thread is preparing the queue and another is sending. I don't get any missing packages on the receiving end, but I can't seem to have a throughput above 320 Mb/s.

Is this what is to be expected or can I do something to improve on this?

Cheers

Henrik

Comment: Is this GigE? How many bytes is each packet? How many packets per second are you seeing? How are you pacing the packets?

Comment: GigE yes. 1400 bytes / packet, 50000 packets/second all received, paced to have equal spacing using the synchronization feature in winpcap. The spacing seems to be working fine when I verify with wireshark.

Comment: My mistake, I meant the timing is working for the transmit part, i.e. it is not just sending everything at once. However, when analyzing the output flow, it varies a lot with time. Is this winpcap causing this?